# Trying to download a file in ASP.NET MVC gives a generic error: "An error occurred while processing the request"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I added this to my controller so I can send a file to the user:

```
else if (bpr.Tag is FileDownloadDirective fdd)
{
    result = File(fdd.Bytes, fdd.ContentType, fdd.FileName);
}
```

where FileDownloadDirective is a custom class which stores information about a file to be downloaded and bpr is an object which stores information about the results of the request that just occurred. However when I do this, I get an alert dialog with the message "An error occurred while processing the request". How can I see the actual error that occurred so I can fix it?

I already have customErrors set to off in the web.config. The byte array contains around 13,000 bytes; the content type is set to the content type for a Word document, and the filename is set to a filename with a .docx extension. Not sure why I'm getting this generic error; any help would be appreciated - thanks!

edit: I did try stepping through the code too but I don't see any error being thrown; I have no idea where the heck this error is coming from...

Comment: Sounds like it's server side, but just in case, have you checked the browser console (F12)?

Comment: Does your class FileDownloadDirective extend ActionResult? What is return type of your controller action where you process download? Also have you set Response.ContentType to your file extension in your controller action?